# second ajax request ignored

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I searched everywhere but I could not find the same problem. Maybe I did a bad search. Sorry.

Here is the issue, I call below function from classic js, the first time it is fired it is ok, completing, but the second and subsequent tries just fail, I think that FADEOUT is not being fired, since I have that DIV staying on the page.

Please advise how can I overcome this issue.

```
var Achtung = function(msg){
 var achtung = $('<div id="achtung">'+msg+'<span class="close">x</span></div>');
 $(achtung)
  .css('position', 'fixed')
  .css('top', '5px')
  .css('display', 'none')
  .css('align','center')
  .css('width', '100%')
  .css('margin-left', 'auto')
  .css('margin-right', 'auto')

 $('body').append(achtung);
 $(achtung).fadeIn(1500);
 var hideTimer = setInterval(hideAchtung, 3000);
 $('#achtung .close').click(function(){hideAchtung();});
}

var hideAchtung = function(){ $('#achtung').fadeOut(500); }
```

and I am calling function from inside a javascript

```
Achtung('Message here...');
```

Comment: Have you tried Firebug? If not, PLEASE make Firebug your friend

Comment: Also, unless I am missing something, you need to add a semicolon after your last .css   (this is confirmed by http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php)

Comment: can you provide working example of issue in jsfiddle or jsbin

Comment: Firebug?? Who or what it is? :)

Comment: a debugger tools, learn to debug will help u a lot

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/masirov/n966g/

Comment: but it is not working there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solved the problem.

```
var hideAchtung = function(){ $('#achtung').fadeOut(500, function(){$('#achtung').remove();}); }
```

Answer (score 0):

just change your code to like this:

```
 $(document).on('click','#achtung .close',function(){hideAchtung();});
```